# Robot Framework RequestsLibrary - What about this cookie is causing a Type Error?

Tags: cookies, python-requests, robotframework

I have a Robot Framework test suite utilizing the [RequestsLibrary](https://github.com/bulkan/robotframework-requests) which tests a RESTful API. The tests work great. A simple sample call:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Test API
    Create API Session
    ${resp} =    Get Request    api_session    /foo/bar
    BlahBlah test the ${resp} etc.


*** Keywords ***
Create API Session
    ${headers_str} =    Evaluate   str('application/json')
    &{headers} =    Create Dictionary    Content-Type=${headers_str}
    Create Session    api_session    ${BASE_URL}    headers=${headers}    verify=True
```

Now I need to start adding cookies for some codeception code coverage tracking to all of the calls made by this test suite. So I adapted the above, working code like so:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Test API
    Create API Session
    ${resp} =    Get Request    api_session    /foo/bar
    BlahBlah test the ${resp} etc.

*** Keywords ***
Create API Session
    ${headers_str} =    Evaluate   str('application/json')
    &{headers} =    Create Dictionary    Content-Type=${headers_str}
    ${cookies_str} =    Evaluate   str('{"CodeCoverage":"Test Name","CodeCoverage_Suite":null,"CodeCoverage_Config":null}')
    &{cookies} =    Create Dictionary    CODECEPTION_CODECOVERAGE=${cookies_str}
    Create Session    api_session    ${BASE_URL}    headers=${headers}    cookies=${cookies}   verify=True
```

But now the `Test API` test fails at the `Get Request` keyword with a perplexing `TypeError: string indices must be integers`. What is going on here? I assume I have misconstructed my cookie, but the documentation has left me more confused than when I started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't an answer to your specific issue, however it does mean what you're attempting to do won't work, even if you do get syntax etc correct.  The RequestsLibrary cannot handle cookies anymore.  Check https://github.com/bulkan/robotframework-requests/blob/master/src/RequestsLibrary/RequestsKeywords.py

Specifically:

```
# cant pass these into the Session anymore
    self.timeout = float(timeout) if timeout is not None else None
    self.cookies = cookies
    self.verify = verify
```

I was driving myself nuts at one point because I needed the cookies passed in to do something, when I found this comment I nearly threw the monitor out the window.  I contacted the author via twitter but never received a response in terms of why this is an issue.  Perhaps I'm even completely misunderstanding the situation myself, I just dumped what I was doing as it was a POC.

Comment: Are you certain that requests can't handle cookies? I think all that comment is saying is that it can't pass cookies to the _session_. It can still pass cookies through each individual _request_. That is why the code saves the cookies (`self.cookies`), and uses them when doing the actual request.

Comment: Nope I'm not certain at all @BryanOakley, hence my suggestion that I could be misunderstanding things, it sounds like I have from your comment.  In my scenario, I needed to pass cookies to the session so I was snookered.

Comment: Bryan has a good point. I remember seeing this when I was digging around in the source code to try to understand this, but I figured I would post the question this way because maybe someone would know that, in fact, you can pass it to the session. I will try to pass the cookies to the individual calls and report back to this question with my findings.

Comment: so your experience this far confirms it isn't possible to pass to the session?  Good luck with the individual calls, based on my experience with Bryan's answers/comments, he is normally spot on.

Comment: Finally got around to giving this a shot. Running into other problems with passing cookies to the specific requests, but I think it will work once I figure that out. I'll open a separate question for that, though.  This is the correct answer to this question as asked. Thanks, shicky!

Comment: Hi, I was just facing something similar and now it started to work...I described it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43543597/robot-framework-pass-cookie-to-get-request-requestslibrary-typeerror/43550528#43550528