# Robot framework pass cookie to get request (RequestsLibrary) - TypeError

Tags: python, cookies, automated-tests, python-requests, robotframework

I need to pass cookie value to Get request keyword to make it work, but it is still failing. I am not sure how to pass it correctly there. Documentation of the keyword says about the headers: "headers: a dictionary of headers to use with the request"
I have test like this, using Library `RequestsLibrary`:

```
Check request and response
    Do Local Login  ${username}    ${password}  #this is my custom keyword - opens browser and logs in using UI
    ${cookie_value}=  Get Cookie Value  JSESSIONID
    Create Session  session1  https://oururl.com  verify=${False}  cookies=${cookie_value}
    ${dict}=  Create Dictionary   Cookie=${cookie_value}
    ${resp}=  Get request  session1  /somepage/request  headers=${dict}
```

It always returns `TypeError: string indices must be integers`. 
Traceback:

```
        Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\RequestsLibrary\RequestsKeywords.py", line 370, in get_request
    session, uri, params, headers, json, redir, timeout)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\RequestsLibrary\RequestsKeywords.py", line 897, in _get_request
    verify=self.verify)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 501, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 474, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 385, in prepare_request
    cookies = cookiejar_from_dict(cookies)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\requests\cookies.py", line 518, in cookiejar_from_dict
    cookiejar.set_cookie(create_cookie(name, cookie_dict[name]))
```

And I really need to pass the cookie to the request, because otherwise it returns back only login page again.

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: Is the last line the one that generates the error?

Comment: Yes, the last one. I added a traceback

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sooo finally found the solution:

```
    Do Local Login  ${username}    ${password}
    ${cookie_value}=  Get Cookie Value  JSESSIONID
    ${dict}=  Create Dictionary   JSESSIONID=${cookie_value}
    Create Session  session1  https://oururl.com  verify=${False}  cookies=${dict}
    ${resp}=  Get request  session1  /somepage/request
```

Keyword `Create Session` works with the cookie, just the cookie must be passed not just as a cookie value, but dictionary  `JSESSIONID=${cookie_value}`.
Alternatively I don't have to pass the cookie in `Create Session` but in `Get Request`, just then I have to make the cookie as dictionary like `${dict}= 
 Create Dictionary   Cookie=JSESSIONID=${cookie_value}` and this pass into `Get request  session1  /somepage/request    headers=${dict}`